# What's the recommended method of cooling flan out of the oven?

Tags: storage-method, refrigerator, flan

I just baked 8 individual flans and want to know how to cool them.   What is the best way to handle the cooling process so that I don't damage the flan and make it easy for them to extract?

I want to just put them all in fridge to set overnight (it's late in the night and making them took way too long). Currently, out of the oven they are too hot to handle and the hot water is hard to grab the ramekins. Can I leave them to cool the water bath for a bit, then transfer the ramekins over to a baking sheet? Do I need to cover them with foil in the fridge? What temperature should I wait for to move them to the fridge? Is there a reason to not put them straight in the fridge (ceramic ramekins). Does it affect the mixing or adhesion of the flan with the caramel if they go in the fridge too soon?

Answer (score 2):

I'd put ice in the water, or dip out the hot water (or suck it out with a baster) and replace with cool water (since the hot water will quickly melt the ice) to get things started cooling faster.

My general custard experience (not flan specific) would suggest putting in the fridge uncovered, or else you get a lot of condensation on the foil or other covering that makes a puddle on the custard. Can be covered once cooled, but don't cover when hot/cooling.